# Who and why was my question on gaslighting techniques been closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Gaslighting has been a topic of current political interest.

Who closed [my question on gaslighting techniques](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/75656/has-gaslighting-been-used-as-a-form-of-political-control-in-the-modern-era-part) and why?

Answer (score 5):

I didn't vote to close* or delete either of your recent posts about gaslighting, but I probably would have if they weren't already closed before I saw them.

The 'who' part of your question is just something I won't address, mostly because I think it's wrong to call out specific people for their votes, and partly because I'm pretty sure it's against some policy to reference specific users like that here on Meta.

For the 'why' part of your question, you have two recent questions about gaslighting, [one closed](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/75654/has-gaslighting-been-used-as-a-form-of-political-control-in-the-modern-era-part) and [one deleted](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/75656/has-gaslighting-been-used-as-a-form-of-political-control-in-the-modern-era-part). While [gaslighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslighting) itself could be related to politics, based on my own interpretation (and various comments) your questions about gaslighting were focused on how it's used by social media companies rather than governments:

- In both questions, you linked a Forbes article that discusses gaslighting, and while the article starts with "We’ve heard the term “gaslighting” a lot over the past year, mostly in politics" the article title is "How To Extinguish Gaslighting In The Workplace", and mostly seems to be related to gaslighting amongst coworkers or by private companies
- In your closed question, you say "One particpant [sic] did admit here on this site that he saw such gaslighting as torture ...". I'm not sure how one person on StackExchange believing gaslighting is torture relates to politics
- You end the closed question by saying "Now by the above, gaslighting is not about physical violence but what is being said or shown. This shows that it is eminently suited to media companies which are in the business of presenting opinion and facts", and while it's great to be critical of social media companies we aren't really a site dedicated to critiques about social media companies
- You end the deleted question by saying "What I'm curious about is whether any social media company has sanctioned such a method as a system of control, within and without", and while it's great to be curious about social media companies we aren't really a site dedicated to curiosity about social media companies

Overall, while gaslighting could be related to governments it's clear you were only asking about the policies of social media companies. While I personally believe a healthy skepticism social media is good, that's not the point of this site: at its core [Politics SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is [about governments](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5850/when-are-the-internal-politics-of-religious-organisations-on-topic/5851#5851), so unless your questions about gaslighting are related to some government policy it will likely be closed as off-topic.

---

*For your deleted post I can't figure out how to see who closed it before it was deleted, and I honestly can't remember if I was one of the close votes or not.

Comment: It lists both of them in separate notices and it was the same moderator who took both actions first closing it as a duplicate of the other question and later deleting it.

Comment: @JoeW Yes, I deleted the duplicate after the asker edited the original question. I previously cast the third and binding close vote on the original question when it was still in its first revision. At that point there was no apparent connection to governmental politics.